# Net Core Scaffold-DBContext CustomCandidateNamingService doesn't work in version 2.0.0-preview1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding

I am using Scaffold-DBContext commnand in order to create a model from my database.
I implemented

```
public class CustomCandidateNamingService : CandidateNamingService
{
    public override string GenerateCandidateIdentifier(string original)
    {
        return original.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

because I want to return the property name all uppercase.
This works in version 1.1.2 but doesn't work in version 2.0.0-preview1-final.

Do I have to change something?

Thanks.

Comment: what is doesn't work? error? nothing happens? also AFAIK cadidatenamingservice was only to be used by EFCore code and not anything outside of it. so they have changed the API. but some error text will help.

Comment: Hi. I mean that th code in GenerateCandidateIdentifier is not executed. I got no errors. The generated members are not in uppercase if I use version 2.0.0-preview1-final. If I use versione 1.1.2 the generated members are in uppercase as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check this repository.
https://github.com/arichika/EFCore2.0-Scaffold-DBContext-CustomCandidateNamingService

You need to change the code.

First, It is necessary to create a new class that inherits IDesignTimeServices.
e.g.

```
public class MyScaffoldingDesignTimeServices: IDesignTimeServices
    {
        public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ICandidateNamingService,
                                   MyScaffoldingCandidateNamingService>();
        }
    }
```

Second, Do this.
e.g.

```
public class MyScaffoldingCandidateNamingService : CandidateNamingService
{
    public override string GenerateCandidateIdentifier(string original)
    {
        return original.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Sample is here. https://github.com/arichika/EFCore2.0-Scaffold-DBContext-CustomCandidateNamingService/blob/master/src/ScaffoldMyDb/MyScaffoldingDesignTimeServices.cs